# Refactoring large switch statement

Tags: java

Lately I have been trying to [extract till I drop](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop). Well not necessarily till I drop, but I've been trying to be more strict and look at some metrics of my code.

I have now come along an old class of mine which has a rather large switch case. Metrics say the method lines of code are beyond evil. It goes something like this:

```
private void startProcessing(Map<MyKeyEnum, String> map) {
    Processor myProcessor = new Processor();
    for (Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
        switch(entry.getKey()) {
            case KEY1:
                myProcessor.processStuffAboutKey1(entry.getValue());
                break;
            case KEY2:
                myProcessor.processStuffAboutKey2(entry.getValue());
                break;
            case KEY3:
                myProcessor.processStuffAboutKey3(entry.getValue());
                break;
            case KEY4:
                myProcessor.processStuffAboutKey4(entry.getValue());
                break;
            ...
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

So basically you can gather that it is necessary for me to invoke very different things for each key **IF** it is in the map. I have therefore already created the `Processor` class and mind you this is already the absolute shortest and most compact that I was able to come up with. Basically this method *does* already do only one thing.

But isn't it possible to build this differently so that it is shorter? I currently have 25+ cases to handle

**Edit:** made clear what `Key,Value`-Pair is and what they're used for

Comment: You're passing in `Map<Key, Value> map` but you're only using the `map.keySet()`. Are you using the `Value`s in the `Map` for anything, or passing them into the `Processor` subroutines?

Comment: **BEEP - BEEP - BEEP!** Strategy Pattern Alert!

Comment: More fundamentally, see if you can't just have one processStuffAboutKey(...) and simply parameterize it based on a string/int, like @dss539. (Are the actions actually key-specific?)

Unless yes, then Strategy Pattern is overkill.

Comment: They are very much key-specific and will do very different things

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg BEEP BEEP BEEP you can also use the visitor pattern for more flexibility but added complexity!

Comment: Although it is something that abounds in java programs, I would strongly recommend against passing containers/collections as parameters & return values. You have no idea what people can/are doing with them - the caller is free to mutate, copy etc etc. It is probably a type waiting to be found.

Comment: @SimonForsberg When I read the question, Strategy Pattern came to mind. But if he has 25+ cases, would not that mean he has to add 25 more classes to apply the Strategy Pattern?

Comment: @LazyNinja Or 25 methods and using lambdas. Java 8 introduces the `Consumer<T>` interface would be useful here, then you can implement each `Consumer<T>` in its own method and refer to them using a lambda.

Comment: @SimonForsberg Thank you! I will look at it. Actually I am facing the same problem which I have posted here .
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/155396/131044
But unfortunately it is put on hold as off topic.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can create a `KeyProcessor` interface and implementation for every key (move the body of the current `Processor.processStuffAboutKeyX()` methods to these classes):

```
public interface KeyProcessor {
    void processStuff(String data);
}
```

Then fill a map with the available implementations:

```
Map<Key, KeyProcessor> processors = new HashMap<>();
processors.add(key1, new Key1Processor());
...
processors.add(key4, new Key2Processor());
```

And use that map in the loop:

```
for (Entry<Key, String> entry: map.entrySet()) {
    Key key = entry.getKey();
    KeyProcessor keyProcessor = processors.get(key);
    if (keyProcessor == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown processor for key " + key);
    }
    final String value = entry.getValue();
    keyProcessor.processStuff(value);
}
```

With the original 25+ cases the switch-case method is at least 75 lines long (25 `case` statement, 25 `break` statement, and at least 1-1 method call line for every case). The separate classes reduces the size and complexity which a developer see at once (+no need to scroll), the code is easier to maintain and test because you can test every case in isolation.

I think it's a lot more easier to have (and handle) a couple of small classes and corresponding *Test classes (with a few test methods for every class) than having a big class (25+ cases) and a lot of tests in one corresponding *Test class or a lot of *Test classes which test separate case branches of the same `startProcessing` method.

I admit that these arguments might be weak ones but without an actual implementation of the `Processor` class and the code which creates the input map is hard to say more.

Further readings:

- *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*: *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism*
- [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say, you beat me to it. StrategyPattern FTW!

Comment: since `Key`is an `enum`, `EnumMap` should be used instead of `HashMap`. It's way more efficient (Effective Java, Item 33)

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Thank you, good point, I've missed that. Write it as an answer, I'd upvote it.

Comment: I don't have much experience in Java, and what I have is very dated, but doesn't Java support first class functions? In C#, I'd probably make a `Dictionary<MyKeyEnum, Action<string>> processorLookup`

Comment: @dss539 https://www.google.com/search?q=java+delegate suggests Java doesn't support such delegates.

Comment: @ChrisW thanks. I just looked and Java 8 still does not support it, even though they added "functional interfaces". It appears that you have to use Scala or Clojure if you want higher order functions in a JVM language. :(  Glad I don't have to use Java.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how is this any better than the `switch` solution? You just moved the 25 "cases" from one function to another (the one which initializes the map), plus you introduced 25 new classes. This is certainly "more object-oriented" than a `switch`, but that doesn't mean it's better.

Comment: The map is only better when you can use key, lambda. If you have to make a new derived class it's the bad.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Good points, I've updated the answer a little bit.

Comment: You could even go ahead and save the corresponding key in the class itself (getProcessedKey()). Thus the creation of all those classes and the filling of the map could be "automated". I used this approach once for a similar problem and found it to be quite maintainable.

Comment: You said "a couple of small classes", but isn't it "25 small classes" (a separate class for each key value)? So the LOC is 25 times however many lines it takes to define a class, plus 25 `processors.add` statements. Also I'm not sure how this would work if, instead of processStuffAboutKey1 etc being various methods of `new Processor` (which can presumably be replaced by diverse new subclasses of Processor), the processStuffAboutKey1 etc were all methods of the class which contains the switch statement.

Comment: I think OO-wise this is the best answer so you'll get my green checkmark. But for future readers I think it's important to keep the comments of @FredOverflow and ChrisW in mind: this will probably not reduce the LOC

Comment: Its worth noting that if you were not using Enums but a non singleton object for the key you could use **Visitor Pattern** but since Java doesn't support multiple dispatch the downside of this approach is an uber interface that knows about all the types (classic *expression problem*).

Comment: The problem with this answer is that your dictionary is, essentially, acting as a vtable. That's all well and good, but the language itself directly supports vtable lookup (i.e. inheritance) Using the built-in vtable (i.e. by creating a base KeyType with a virtual method `processStuff`) requires fewer LOC and is easier to maintain because it is DRY.

Comment: @ChrisW: Yes, it's 25 small classes. I think LOC is not so important. It's interesting to see that what we do just (in general) to break a complex problem to manageable smaller chunks (otherwise we could use one class with one main method without line breaks). I think having small classes makes it easier to cope with. I agree with *Carsten*, I've used this a few times and it was really enjoyable to work with.

Comment: @ChrisW: If I understand correctly the second part, it could be more complex and harder to manage because the `processStuffAboutKey` method could access other fields (not just the passed String value). I might not access other fields/methods, but a maintainer can't be sure at first sight.

Comment: Moving away from switch is better as it promote open-close principle. Now generating this map can be even configurable, for e.g. reading keys from file and instantiating respective objects using runtime support, if needed. Which is not be possible with switch.

Answer (score 12):

How about adding the functionality of the process methods to the enum itself? This way the enum itself knows how to process, and if you add a value to the enum you don't have to search for all switch statements in your code base to update these.

You can read more about this approach in Effective Java, by Joshua Bloch.

Something like this:

````
private void startProcessing(Map<MyKeyEnum, String> map) {
    for (Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
    entry.getKey().process(entry.getValue());
    }
}


public enum MyKeyEnum {
    VALUE1 {
        public void process(String s) {
            // do specific processing for VALUE1
        }
    },
    VALUE2 {
        public void process(String s) {
            // do specific processing for VALUE2
        }
    }
    ...
    ;

    public abstract void process(String s);
}
```
````

Comment: This is a good idea for small enums, but it is going to get messy when the enum grows. I'd prefer the EnumMap solution

Comment: With the EnumMap solution you still have the boilerplate code to add all the processors to the map, and 25+ Processor classes. I think it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah for this answer I'd say so, too. But could you give the exact item number in Effective Java you are referring to please?

Comment: This solution is the cleanest. You have identified the core problem being that `MyKeyEnum` really should be a base class with derived types KEY1, KEY2, etc. IMO, this enum shouldn't be an enum. Switch statement's like the OP's are a code smell that indicates an opportunity for polymorphism.

Comment: @avalancha Item 30 in Effective Java 2nd edition. Look for the example with enum Operator, and onwards.

Answer (score 7):

You can replace each case in the switch statement with a virtual function call, as shown in palacsint's answer.

IMO palacsint's answer is little better (and arguably worse: more lines of code) than the original code. For example when you need to add support for a new key value, in your code you need to add a new case statement, and in palacsint's code you need to add a new class (derived from `KeyProcessor`) and add a new entry to the `processors` map.

palacsint's strategy is much more worth implementing if you have **two** switch statements which do various things based on the key value (in which case `KeyProcessor` has more than one abstract method, a different method to replace each switch statement). Having one such switch statement isn't necessarily a bad idea.

See also [Large Switch statements: Bad OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/505454/49942)

Also, you haven't said what types `Key` and `Value` are:perhaps one of these types could be constructed such that it contains an appropriate abstract method.

Comment: The `key` is an `enum` I built and the `value` is `String`. Edited the question accordingly

Comment: You can put `processStuff` method in the `enum` using strategy pattern.

Comment: @avalancha How do you build the enum values? Instead of creating enum values, can you create instances of subclasses of an abstract class instead (or, select a flightweight singleton of a subclass)?

Answer (score 5):

An addition to the strategy and code of @palacsint is to use `Reflection` to automatically bind the classes that implement `KeyProcessor` to the dictionary. This way, you don't have to add each `KeyProcessor` manually and you don't have to remember it.

Make sure that you only 'reflect' once because it is relatively slow. Thus add it to a static block or in the constructor of a singleton.

Comment: I don't think using reflection would be a good advise

Comment: @GonzaloNaveira: Please elaborate. IMO **instead of remembering, I implement rules** via Reflection.

Comment: @Mimpen IMO in this case it doesn't worth it and I don't even mention the problems regarding the performances issues, refactoring and error prone it could be. By the other hand, yes, **somethimes** reflection is great; but not always.

Answer (score 5):

Your enum should actually be a base class with the virtual method `processStuff(string)`.
Each key should be it's own class and should implement the virtual method.

This approach is similar to answer by [Paul S](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/42153/30851) but is more true to OO style.

Applying the strategy pattern here is not a good idea in my opinion because it hides the core design problem and creates a lot of boilerplate.

Of course, I'm not a fan of the strategy pattern in general:

> The Strategy pattern is beautiful on the surface, but Strategy objects are typically stateless, which means they're really just first-order functions in disguise. (If they have state, then they're Closures in disguise.) Etc. You either get this, because you've done functional programming before, or you don't, in which case I sound like I'm a babbling idiot, so I guess I'll wrap it up.

https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid

Comment: +1. It does not have two similar object inheritance trees (which is a smell); encapsulates the data and operation in the same class; if you have a new key you just have to create a new subclass and don't have to modify the code in several places, you won't forget to add a case to the switch, etc. (single responsibility principle, DRY); and you don't have a long class, just small ones. (But I'd use an interface, not an abstract parent class. :)

Answer (score 0):

In line with @M. Mimpen's answer, get all methods of `Processor` object and store them in `Map<MyKeyEnum, Method>`, where the key refers to the key from your parameter `map`.

An alternative to this, is putting an entry to Map every time an entry is added to your `map` (the one you pass to the method).

```
//assume there is a populated Map<MyKeyEnum, Method>. Let's say it's named processorMethodMap

 private void startProcessing(Map<MyKeyEnum, String> map) {
    Processor myProcessor = new Processor();
    for (Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {
         //call the appropriate method
         processorMethodMap.get(entry.getValue()).invoke(<pass argument(s) here>);
    }
 }
```